# \tableofcontents doesn't display after using titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, texlive, babel, titlesec, hebrew

*I am fairly new to LaTeX so sorry it's a weird question. Also, English is not my native language so I apologize in advance for any grammar mistakes I make.*

I am writing a LaTeX document in Hebrew using the package babel. Here is the document's code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, hebrew]{babel}

\title{בדיקה למסמך בשפה העברית}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{פתיחה}

זוהי פסקה בשפה העברית. מסמך זה בודק את יכולות השפה העברית של \L{\LaTeX} . אני אכתוב פסקה יחסית ארוכה כדי לראות אם זה כותב את השורות כמו שצריך. אני אמשיך לכתוב כאן קצת...... עוד קצת.....

אוקיי! אני עכשיו אכתוב עוד פסקה כדי לראות אם זה עבד.

\section{עוד משהו}
אני עכשיו סתם אכתוב ג'יבריש כדי לראות אם החרא של התוכן עניינים עובד.

גכעגכיעדמאימיעכ סעכ חסעעמ כעויןגסוי גלחמנעכמבעכ גחח

כ עיןוגכעו ינוצכע כחענצצןאניויתןןוצוציןיןחמחמחמחמ

\section{דבר נוסף}

\subsection{דבר נוסף מספר 1}
דברים דברים דברים ועוד דברים.

\subsection{דבר נוסף מספר 2}
מלא דברים מיותרים בלה בלה בלה בלה בלה בלה לבס הלב הל  חכגעצידמצחאםטמצםארד יחכע 

גכינןכמויעגננסלגכתעצנלךסגכצענץ.

\section{אחרון ודי}

\begin{enumerate}
\item דבר אחד
\item עוד דבר
\item דבר אחד אחרון
\begin{enumerate}
\item דבר בתוך דבר
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This is how the document looks after compiling it using pdflatex:

[image]

I personally don't like to have numbers in the section titles so I put the following code before `\begin{document}` to make the numbers disappear:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\large\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalsize\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}
```

When writing documents in English, these commands work perfectly without any problem but when I compile Hebrew documents with those commands, the table of contents disappears:
[image]

I need to write a long essay in Hebrew so not putting a table of contents is not an option for me. Is there a way to fix this?

Some info that might be helpful: I use Texlive on Arch Linux. The Texlive packages I have installed are texlive-core, texlive-fontsextra, texlive-langextra, texlive-latexextra and texlive-culumus (from the AUR).

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` drops the numbers: the headings "will be not numbered but they will be included in both toc and headers" (manual, p12). At a guess, `\titleformat` looks like it just formats whatever is there, so a `{}` applies no format. Setting the sectioning counters to empty, `\renewcommand\thesection{}` etc, is the low-level way of removing numbers. I can't get your code to compile (on Windows), so cannot test fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to remove the section numbers, there is no need to use `titlesec`. As suggested by @Cicada, try with the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, hebrew]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{בדיקה למסמך בשפה העברית}
```

I get:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `section*`, with `\addcontentsline`.
[image: toc]

```
\documentclass[hebrew]{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{FreeSans}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\else
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english, main=hebrew]{babel}
\fi


\title{בדיקה למסמך בשפה העברית}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{פתיחה}
\section*{פתיחה}

זוהי פסקה בשפה העברית. מסמך זה בודק את יכולות השפה העברית של {\L{\LaTeX} . אני אכתוב פס} ארוכה כדי לראות אם זה כותב את השורות כמו שצריך. אני אמשיך לכתוב כאן קצת...... עוד קצת.....

אוקיי! אני עכשיו אכתוב עוד פסקה כדי לראות אם זה עבד.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{עוד משהו}
\section*{עוד משהו}

אני עכשיו סתם אכתוב ג'יבריש כדי לראות אם החרא של התוכן עניינים עובד.

גכעגכיעדמאימיעכ סעכ חסעעמ כעויןגסוי גלחמנעכמבעכ גחח

כ עיןוגכעו ינוצכע כחענצצןאניויתןןוצוציןיןחמחמחמחמ

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{דבר נוסף}
\section*{דבר נוסף}

\stepcounter{subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{דבר נוסף מספר}
\subsection*{דבר נוסף מספר 1}
דברים דברים דברים ועוד דברים.

\stepcounter{subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{דבר נוסף מספר}
\subsection*{דבר נוסף מספר 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP is clearly using `pdftex` and your solution requires `xetex`.